# Avoiding Loss of Work with Local Commits?

Tags: git

I am new to Git, having only tinkered with it.  I really like it so far, and we are talking about starting to use it where I work.

One of the questions that has come up (that I can't answer), is a scenario where developers  committing locally over a long period of time as their work is not yet ready to push to the central repository.  How does one avoid losing the work of a developer should their hard disk crash?

Is it a best practice to mirror the local repository on a network share, or something along those lines?

Comment: I'd probably recommend a branch, so you can push to that branch whenever you want without disrupting the mainline. Or another alternative is to push to a separate place on the network, a totally separate repository. Or there's always traditional cloud backup of the local machine like DropBox or Carbonite or something like that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> developers committing locally over a long period of time as their work is not 
>   yet ready to push to the central repository.

But their work *is* ready. A developer can branch off the `master` branch

```
git checkout master
git branch experiment
git checkout experiment
```

Now once they are done with some experimental work, they can push the experimental branch without affecting the `master` branch

```
git push origin experiment
```

Then when the time is right you can either merge the branch

```
git checkout master
git merge experiment
```

or delete the branch

```
git branch -d experiment
```

You will notice the [official Git repo](http://github.com/git/git/branches)
does this

```sh
master  # main branch
next    # soon to be merged to master
pu      # proposed updates
```

Comment: +1 — but a note on branch naming: Have your devs name the branch after what they are working on – like `feature/print-money`. If they are just messing around, use something like `personal/tom`. What you need to remember about git is: **branching is cheap – as cheap as it gets**. Just remember to give those sensible names, so you understand your list of branches later on.

Comment: So is branching more common in the git workflow vs. something like svn (which is what I have used for the last several years)?  From my experience, people using SVN tend to branch only for major features, not for each person working a ticket.

Comment: @PhilSandler yes, because with Git branches only cost 10 bytes or so, so they can be easily created and destroyed.

Answer (score 1):

Trying to use git to just have a synced copy of my in-work files is too much of a headache, and I found that I spent more time fighting over things with git (and making messy commits like "updated", "updated #2", "updated #3") than I did developing.

I use a combination of a seperate branch/remote and a "cloud" (even though I hate using that term) backup solution like dropbox that saves the current "dirty" state of my repo. That way I can open my laptop, and immediately pick up where I left off without having to try pull down / merge my changes.

Another thing to note, is that git is NOT for backup, even though it's distributed nature makes it a lot easier to recover work when things go wrong. That's what backup scripts are for :)